# Unable to convert bigdata tuple to dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tuples

I am dealing with a big data having more than million rows and 20 columns. Though my code works fine in sample tuple given below, it fails in bigdata

```
ata = [('Facebook', 750, True),
        ('Alphabet', 1100, True),
        ('Amazon', 1700, True),
        ('Apple', 2100, False),
        ('Microsoft', 1750, False)]
```

I am trying to convert them to a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(testdata, columns=cols)
```

Though the above code, works in sample data, I get an error message when I do the same on real data like as given below

> ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 10116838, 20)

While I know there are `10116838` rows and `20` columns in the realdata, I don't know from where does it pick that `1` as 1st dimension. Is it referring to the index?

Can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe test `pd.DataFrame.from_records`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(testdata, columns=cols)
```

output:

```
           A     B      C
0   Facebook   750   True
1   Alphabet  1100   True
2     Amazon  1700   True
3      Apple  2100  False
4  Microsoft  1750  False
```

Another possibility, most likely, is that your input is invalid and that there are tuples with less/more values. You should try to bisect your large data to find out examples where it fails.

##### edit: example with missing data

```
testdata = [('Facebook', 750, True),
            ('Alphabet',),
            ('Amazon', 1700, True),
            ('Apple', 2100),
            ('Microsoft', 1750, False)]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(testdata, columns=list('ABC'))
```

output:

```
           A       B      C
0   Facebook   750.0   True
1   Alphabet     NaN   None
2     Amazon  1700.0   True
3      Apple  2100.0   None
4  Microsoft  1750.0  False
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted..but from-records doesn't work as it just returns column names

Comment: what do you mean by `tuples with less/more values`.... Yes, my tuple may have missing values/NA's for certain rows/columns

Comment: I provided an example with missing data, it should work fine, make sure that you have tuples (i.e., if a single value use `(value,)`, not `(value)`

Comment: When I type `testdf` in jupyter cell to display my tuple, it returns the dimensions like below `[10116838 rows x 20 columns],)`

Comment: but only when I try to convert them to dataframe, it throws error with shape `(1, 10116838, 20)`

Comment: @TheGreat have you tried bisecting your data? split the list in two, test the code on the halves, pick one for which it fails, start over until you get a reasonable size example, then you can paste it here