# return multiple objects from a recursive function using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a function like as below

```
def fun1():                 
  do something
  ....
  return df1,df2

def fun2(df1,df2):
  ...
  df3 = df1.merge(df2)
  do something
  return df3   

funcs = [fun1, fun2]
op_data = []
for func in funcs:
    op_data = func(*op_data)
```

But the above works, if I wish to return only `df3`. It goes and neatly gets stored in `op_data`.

However, what if I want to return `df1,df2 and df3` from `fun2`.

I wish to access all df1,df2 and df3 after function execution. Currently am able to access only `df3`. but how can I access `df1` and `df2` the same way?

Comment: Why not use `return df1, df2, df3` in `fun2`?

Comment: yes Shaido. If I return df1,df2 and df3 where will they get stored?

Comment: will all of them get stored in op-data? and how to access the,

Comment: Yes, op_data will be a tuple with the 3 dataframes. It's the same logic as when you return `df1, df2` from `fun1`.

Comment: Hi Shaido, if I do that, I encounter the below issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388680/unable-to-convert-bigdata-tuple-to-dataframe-using-pandas

Comment: Additionally, may I also check why is `op_data` a tuple, instead of a list? because I have defined  op_data as a list initially?

Comment: hi @TheGreat.  You can return return df1, df2, df3 as suggested.  If you want it to be a list, after return, you can use list() to convert to list.  then add to op_data

Comment: `op_data` will be overwritten in each iteration of the loop (so whether you initialize it or not, the result will be the same). When returning multiple objects from a function these will be returned as a tuple by default (see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345995/how-does-python-return-multiple-values-from-a-function/39346392).

Comment: thanks for your help. Understood, If it can be written as an answer, I would be happy to mark and upvoted it

Comment: return df1, df2, df3.  ###  for func in funcs:     op_data += list(func(*op_data))  ### issues is that there is an error when you call func with *list.  I normally see the parameters given to a function as dict.  Assuming that part is solved, then return df1, df2, df3 and use list() around the return tuple will convert to a list.

Answer (score 1):

I just give this a try... ;-)

```
def fun1(*args):                 
    df1 = args[0]
    df2 = args[1]
    return df1,df2

def fun2(*args):
    df1 = args[0]
    df2 = args[1]
    df3 = df1.merge(df2)
    return df1, df2, df3

funcs = [fun1, fun2]
op_data = [df1,df2]
for func in funcs:
    op_data += list(func(*op_data))
```